# Issue with finding second highest salary in sql

Tags: mysql

I am having a table looks like below.

[image: Table schema]

I need second highest salary of all the employess table.

When I do below query  I am getting expected result:

[image: Expected result]

But it giving me empty result when i do

```
SELECT id,employee_id,name,salary 
FROM `employess` 
WHERE id not in (
    select id from `employess`
    where 1 
    group by employee_id 
    order by id desc)  
GROUP BY employee_id 
order by salary desc;
```

Second highest salaries of all the employess.

Comment: The subquery returns *all* the employees. So `WHERE id NOT IN (...)` excludes all employees, and you get an empty result.

Answer (score 0):

The subquery returns all employee IDs, so excluding them in the main query excludes everyone.

Change the subquery so it just returns the highest salary. Then exclude that salary, order by salary, and return the first of that.

```
SELECT id,employee_id,name,salary 
FROM `employess` 
WHERE salary != (
    SELECT MAX(salary)
    FROM employess
)
ORDER BY salary DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Or return the ID of the employee with the highest salary and exclude them.

```
SELECT id,employee_id,name,salary 
FROM `employess` 
WHERE id != (
    SELECT id
    FROM employess
    ORDER BY salary DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
ORDER BY salary DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: The second query is not equivalent to the first if there is more than one employee with the same max salary, or if the employee with the max salary also has a row with the 2nd highest salary. Apart from that, I think OP is looking for the 2nd highest salary per employee, not the 2nd highest salary overall.

Comment: It's not clear what they want. They have `GROUP BY employee_id`, but that appears to be a unique ID so grouping makes little sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the `dense_rank` function in MySQL to sort employees based on their highest salaries. Then, you filter the results using the `where` clause to obtain the second-highest salary from employees, as you desire.

```
with cte_employees as
(
    select dense_rank() over (partition by employee_id order by salary desc) as rank,
           id,
           employee_id,
           name,
           salary
    from employees
)
select id, employee_id, name, salary
from cte_employees
where rank = 2;
```

For further information about `dense_rank`, you can visit the [official MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_dense-rank).